# Wait until unknown number of ajax request done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm uploading a list of documents to the server, and for each document I launch an ajax request, but the number of requests is unknown (Depends on the number of document being uploaded). How can I show a message to the user when all the documents are uploaded (All ajax requests are done).

```
$.each(files,function(idx,elm){
                    let formData = new FormData();
                    let ID = '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
                    formData.append('document_id', ID);
                    formData.append('file-doc', elm);
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/add_multiple_docs",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                            function getCookie(name) {
                                var cookieValue = null;
                                if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                                    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                                        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                                        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                return cookieValue;
                            }

                            if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                                // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
                            }
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        },
                        failure: function (request) {
                            console.log(request);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                            console.log("error add document");
                            let msg = '';
                            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                            } else if (jqXHR.status === 404) {
                                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                            } else if (jqXHR.status === 500) {
                                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                msg = 'Time out error.';
                            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                            } else {
                                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                            }
                            console.log(msg)
                        }
                    });
                });                
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you know how many files are uploaded, so you know how many ajax request you are doing. (1 Request per file)

So before your `$.each()` fires you get the size of `files`

```
let count = $(files).size();

$.each(files,function(idx,elm){
/*your code with requests*/
}
```

Now, after each ajax request hast fired, decrement `count`. Decrement inside your `success` and `failure` methods, because it doesn't mattet if it succeeded or not. And check if `count === 0`. If it's 0 than you know all ajax are done.

```
$.ajax({
/*your other settings*/
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        count--;

        doSomething(count);
    },
    failure: function (request) {
        console.log(request);
        count--;

        doSomething(count);
    },
});

function doSomething(count){
    if(count === 0){
        /*stuff you wannna do after all ajax requests are done*/
    }
}
```

I haven't done that many ajax for now, so I'm not quite sure if `failure` is also fired on `error`, but if not maybe add `count--` and the if on error as well.

Comment: But you better use the answer from Rory McCrossan with promise

Comment: When should I call doSomething function ? In an infinite loop !

Comment: If the loop were infinite, you wouldn't be able to wait for it to be done. It's just un unknown number ob ajax requests, but at runtime you know how many ajax request are being done. Therefore, after each ajax is done (doesn't matter if it fails or not) you can check if it was the last ajax.

Comment: Oh yes, got it thnks.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you need you can place all the jqXHR objects returned from `$.ajax()` in an array which you can `apply()` to `$.when()`. Then you can execute whatever logic you require after all of those promises have been resolved. Try this:

```js
var promises = files.map(function(elm) {
  // setup formData...

  return $.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/add_multiple_docs",
    // ajax settings...
  });
});

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
  console.log('all requests complete, do something here...');
});
```

*However*, it's definitely worth noting that sending AJAX requests in a loop is not a scalable pattern to use. It would be a much better idea to aggregate all the file and related data in a single AJAX request and handle that once on the server.

Comment: I was getting an error 'files.map' is not a function, so I used this instead Array.from(files).map. The ajax getting excuted but the $.when function not executing and I'm not seeing any message in the console.

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting question.

I had a similar issue when trying to get data from the youtube API which only returned a max result set of 50 items.

To solve this problem I used a recursive function that accepted a callback, on base case (in my case when there was no nextPageToken) I called the callback function.

The recursion was triggered in the success handler of the $.ajax request.

```
    function fetchVideos(nextPageToken, callback) {
        if (nextPageToken === null || nextPageToken === undefined) {
            callback(null);
            return;
        }

        $.ajax(requestURI + `&pageToken=${nextPageToken}`, {
            success: (data) => {
                // use data somehow?
                fetchVideos(data.nextPageToken, callback);
            },

            error: (err) => {                    
                callback(err);
            }
        })
    }

    fetchVideos("", (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.responseJSON);
            return;
        }
        updateUI();
    })
```

When there was no longer a nextPageToken in the response it would trigger the if statement. I think it works kind of sync? Because I need the nextPageToken to perform the next request.

I know this is not the best case for you situation, but I answered based on the title which is how I came to this page :)